# Capture MKMapView screenshot different in iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, mkmapview

I would like to get screenshot of mapview. So i used following code. This code works perfectly in ipad and simulator but not on ipod. The iPad has iOS 6.0 and my xcode is 4.2.1 and the iPod has iOS 5.0.

```
- (UIImage*) renderToImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size);
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    return viewImage;
}
```

The problem is, i have got same image in iPad, iPod ans simulator but not names corresponding manual screen capture and programatic screen capture.The names are very big in iPod, at the same time names are normal in iPad and simulator and also some names are invisible in iPod.That is the my problem.

The following images are:

This image belongs to iPod manual screen capture.

[image]

This image belongs to iPod programatic screen capture.

[image]

I don't know where the problem is. Please help me anyone.

Comment: iOS 5 uses Google Maps for its mapping service. iOS 6 uses Apple's in-house mapping service. In both cases you're getting exactly what you would in Maps.app and what the user expects. On the names front it looks like Google does states and cities but Apple only does cities?

Comment: The names are very big in iPod, at the same time names are normal in iPad and simulator and also some names are invisible in iPod.That is the my problem.

Comment: Prasad: Tommy is saying that's to be expected. Apple changed how mapping works between iOS 5.0 (on your iPod) and iOS 6.0 (on your iPad and in the simulator). If you want to see the same image on all your devices, upgrade your iPod to iOS 6.0.

Comment: @Tim :I have updated my question. I think the problem is, loading the mapview or its layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size);` here. I have just replaced this to  `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView.frame.size, NO, 0.0);`. Then it is working in iOS 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell by looking at the app in each situation, it's not your screenshot code that is magically creating different maps, *the underlying maps are different*.

Comment: Thank you for replay. My problem before capturing and after capturing the images are different. I think the problem is in loading the mapview. I have updated my question. Please tell me answer of my problem.

Comment: I'm unclear about your before/after state. Are the screen shots posted above taken by your app, or by you pressing the home and screen-lock button?

Comment: First image is derived from me means pressing the home and screen-lock button and second image is derived from given code. The both images are not same.

Comment: I think then you need to change your wording. It's not before vs after capturing, your screen is still the same after the screen capture takes place. It is manual screen capture vs programatic screen capture.

Comment: Thank you Craig for replaying and your patience.