# Screenshot of MKMapView doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, screenshot

This is my code:

What am I doing wrong?? I simply want to take a screenshot of an MKMapView displaying a given Location. Taking the screenshot and placing it in an UIImage works fine, but the MKMapView looks really wierd, as if it hasn't been rendered. What's wrong?

if(PageControllerMain.currentPage == 0) {

```
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(MainPage1MapContainer.bounds.size, MainPage1MapContainer.opaque, 0.0);

    }

    else {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(MainPage1MapContainer.bounds.size, MainPage1MapContainer.opaque, 0.0);
    [MainPage1MapContainer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:@"MapImagePage1.png" atomically:YES];


    OverallMainMapContainer.image = image;


}
```

[image: MKMapView doens't display location]

Comment: Try this for your UIImage* 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);

Comment: I just tried it, but it just shows the same result? Am I looking at this the wrong way, is this a legal problem with the Apple Maps App?

Comment: I shouldnt think so... Im sorry that I cant be much more help with your answer. Try these links though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834838/capture-mkmapview-screenshot-different-in-ios-5-and-ios-6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159596/make-a-uiimage-from-a-mkmapview

Comment: Bummer man, I will keep digging. Let us know if you get it sorted